# Logical OR in my shell script

Tags: bash, shell

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.ats;
do
    if [[ ("${file}" = THx) || ("${file}" = THy)]]
    then cp $file /home/milenko/procmt
    fi
done
```

Files in directory

```
262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_128H.ats
262_V01_C01_R000_TEy_BL_128H.ats
262_V01_C02_R000_THx_BL_128H.ats
262_V01_C03_R000_THy_BL_128H.ats
```

What I wanted is to copy the files that contain THx or THy,but files are not copied.
Why?

Comment: `cp *_TH[xy]_*.ats /home/milenk/procmt/`? No point to having a loop at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) for extended globbing? This way you can use the `for` itself to get the required extensions:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *TH?(x|y)*.ats; do
   # do things with "$file" ...
done
```

`*TH?(x|y)*.ats` expands to those files containing `<something> + TH + either x or y + <something> + .ats`

---

**Your script fails because you have a typo in it**:

```
if [[ ("${file}" = THx) || ("${file}" = THy)]]
#                                          ^
#                              missing space
```

This is fine:

```
$ d="hi"
$ [[ ($d == hi) || ($d == ha) ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

Although the parentheses are superfluous:

```
$ [[ $d == hi || $d == ha ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

Comment: Unless `x` and `y` are represent multicharacter strings, `?(x|y)` is equivalent to the ordinary pattern `[xy]`.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can avoid a loop entirely here:

```
cp *TH[xy]*.ats /home/milenko/procmt
```

There's no need to loop through the results and then do a separate comparison; a single glob will expand to the list of files that you want.

There were a couple of problems with your original approach:

- Firstly, you were trying to test for exact matches, so the condition would never be true.
- Also, take care with spaces: `]]` is a keyword in the compound command `[[`, so it needs to be a separate word (i.e. surrounded by spaces).

Comment: One caveat: the loop is necessary if you are expecting more matches than could fit on one command line. Also, on an extremely pedantic note, `]` is an argument to the *simple* command `[`, but `[[ ... ]]` is a *compound* command using keywords `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the wording. So is the length limit of the `for` loop greater than it would be for the `cp` command?

Comment: In either case, the pattern is passed to whatever library function expands the pattern. For an external command, you need the entire result to construct one large argument list to pass to a call in the `exec*` family. The size of that argument list is subject to an OS-specific size limit. For an internal command, the shell is in control the whole time, so it only needs to grab one file at a time from the result to process the body.

Answer (score 5):

Your question specifies "files that contain THx or THy" ... but your code specifies that the file name **is** THx or THy.

Comment: No filename matching the pattern `*.ats` will be `THy` nor `THx`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use character class in glob i.e. `*TH[xy]*` to check if `$file` contains `THx` or `THy`:

```
for file in *.ats; do
    if [[ $file == *TH[xy]* ]]; then
       cp "$file" /home/milenko/procmt
    fi
done
```